ML-Kit Document Scanner lifecycle callbacks
Can't get the App Lifcycle while ml-kit is opened.
class MyApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(AppLifecycleTracker())
    }


    inner class AppLifecycleTracker : ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
        override fun onActivityCreated(activity: Activity, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {}
        override fun onActivityStarted(activity: Activity) {}
        override fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {}
        override fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {}
        override fun onActivityStopped(activity: Activity) {
            if (activity is GmsDocumentScanningDelegateActivity)
                Utils.removeWindowManager(baseContext)
        }
        override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(activity: Activity, outState: Bundle) {}
        override fun onActivityDestroyed(activity: Activity) {
            if (activity is GmsDocumentScanningDelegateActivity)
                Utils.removeWindowManager(baseContext)
        }
    }

When the user put the app in the background, No lifecycle callback executed (onActivityStopped()),
So i can't call Utils.removeWindowManager(baseContext) When the app goes in the background
I tryed this but onEnterBackground is called when user open the scanner but no execution when the app goes in the background.
class AppLifecycleObserver : LifecycleObserver {

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun onEnterForeground() {
        // App has entered the foreground
        // Do something, if needed
        log("App entered foreground")
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun onEnterBackground() {
        // App has entered the background
        // Do something, if needed
        log("App entered background")
    }
    
    private fun log(message: String) {
        // Replace with your preferred logging method
        println(message)
    }
}

